# Kind of recursive usage of an Component possible?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, components

After searching for like two hours for a solution I decided to ask some pros suspecting the solution could be quite simple.

It is an Angular7 project.
I would like to have a "goal" in my goals component with a button "+". When you click that button I want to have annother goal being added to the page. So I want to click a button of the goal component to create a new goal, which is something like recursive to me.

goals.component.html:

```
<input type="text" value="Ich brauche einen Laptop für maximal 1000 Euro.">
<br/>
<br/>
<app-goal id="{{lastGivenId+1}}"></app-goal>
```

goals.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-goals',
  templateUrl: './goals.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./goals.component.scss']
})
export class GoalsComponent implements OnInit {
  lastGivenId: number = 0;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

goal.component.ts and goal.component.html:

```js
//Typescript code
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-goal',
  templateUrl: './goal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./goal.component.scss']
})
export class GoalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id : number;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  onAddLowerGoal(currentGoalID:number){
    // var goalElement = document.registerElement('app-goal');
    // document.body.appendChild(new goalElement());
    let newGoal = document.createElement("app-goal");
    newGoal.setAttribute("id", "999");
    let currentGoal = document.getElementById(currentGoalID.toString());
    document.body.insertBefore(newGoal, currentGoal);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
<div id="{{id}}" class="goal">goal{{id}}</div>
<button id="AddLowerGoal1" (click)="onAddLowerGoal(999)">+</button>
</html>
```

This way, it creates an app-goal element, but the div and button elements within the app-goal element is missing.
How can this problem be solved? Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First glance: delete the `html` tags from your `goal.component.html` file.

Next: you can recursively add `app-goal` using angular. Inserting `app-goal` element the javascript way only adds the `<app-goal></app-goal>` object. It doesn't create an angular component. It doesn't bind your data.

Also if you're using Angular's `@Input`, you need to assign a component input with square braces. Do not use tags.

goals.component.html:

```
<input type="text" value="Ich brauche einen Laptop für maximal 1000 Euro.">
<br/>
<br/>
<app-goal [id]="lastGivenId+1"></app-goal>
```

goal.component.html:

```
<div id="{{id}}" class="goal">goal{{id}}</div>
<button id="AddLowerGoal1" (click)="onAddLowerGoal(999)">+</button>
<div *ngFor="let subGoal of subGoals">
  <app-goal [id]="subGoal.id"></app-goal>
</div>
```

goal.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-goal',
  templateUrl: './goal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./goal.component.scss']
})
export class GoalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() id : number;
  subGoals: Array<any> = [];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() { }

  onAddLowerGoal(currentGoalID: number){
    this.subGoals.push({id: currentGoalID});
  }
}
```

You can also use a service to store your goals and subgoals to access them later.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is a Reactive Form with `FormArray` with dynamically added form controls.

Take a look at this for eg:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({...})
export class GoalsComponent  {

  goalsForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.goalsForm = this.fb.group({
      goals: this.fb.array([])
    });
  }

  onFormSubmit() {
    console.log('Form Value: ', this.goalsForm.value);
  }

  get goals() {
    return (<FormArray>this.goalsForm.get('goals')).controls;
  }

  addGoal() {
    (<FormArray>this.goalsForm.get('goals')).push(this.fb.control(null));
  }

}
```

And here's the template for this:

```
<h2>Goals:</h2>
<form [formGroup]="goalsForm" (submit)="onFormSubmit()">
  <button type="button" (click)="addGoal()">Add Goal</button>
  <hr>
  <div *ngFor="let goal of goals; let i = index;" formArrayName="goals">
    <div>
      <label for="goal">Goal {{ i + 1 }}: </label>
      <input type="text" id="goal" [formControlName]="i">
    </div>
    <br>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <button>Submit Form</button>
</form>
```

Here's a [**Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-goals-eg?file=src/app/app.component.html) for your ref.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. But what I'd like to happen in your Sample StackBlitz is that when clicking the Add button there would apper annother Add button. The thing is I want to have an upper goal and be able to create a lower goal to that upper goal.

Comment: And then each lower goal will have it's own lower goal?

Comment: Exactly. Each goal (upper or lower goal) can have it's own lower goal, but it doens't need to.

Comment: There can also be multiple lower goals to an upper goal. Every goal shall have a name (I used a div element in order to present the name) and it's add button to create a lower goal.